# pentaho cde export button- how tp set the export file name?

Tags: export, pentaho, pentaho-cde

The pentaho cde export component is working for me , it export the table data and the file name is cda-export.csv, can I set the file name atomically?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call exportData with the parameter {filename : 'myfilename'}

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand well how the parameters map to the actual Js function, but in the Expression parameter of a Button component, the following can be done:

```
function exportData(){
    render_YourComponentName.queryState.exportData('xls', null,  {filename:'custom_name.csv'});
}
```